# how to detect datetime field in dataframe using regular expression in python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, strftime

I am trying to return the filed in the dataframe that is of type datetime and than replace the field name with "date" in order to split the datetime into year and months.

when I run the code it crash and display the below error:

```
   df = df.rename(columns={converteddate[0]: 'date'})
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'converteddate' referenced before assignment
```

## code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'event_type': ['watch movie ', 'stay at home', 'swimming','camping','meeting'], 
               'date': ['8/11/2020', '2/13/2020', '7/04/2020','1/22/2020','7/28/2020'],
                'event_mohafaza':['loc1','loc3','loc2','loc5','loc4'],
                 ' number_person ':[24,39,20,10,33],})
        
non_numeric_cols = [col for col, col_type in df.dtypes.iteritems() if col_type == 'object']
if len(non_numeric_cols) > 0:
         mask = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x : x.str.match('[0-3]?[0-9]-[0-3]?[0-9]-(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}$').any())
            
         if mask.any() == True:
               df.loc[:,mask] = df.loc[:,mask].apply(pd.to_datetime,dayfirst=False)
               converteddate = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype == 'datetime64[ns]']
         df = df.rename(columns={converteddate[0]: 'date'})
         if "date" in df.columns:
               df['year_month'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y/%m'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify your regex the match works:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'event_type': ['watch movie ', 'stay at home', 'swimming','camping','meeting'], 
               'date': ['8/11/2020', '2/13/2020', '7/04/2020','1/22/2020','7/28/2020'],
                'event_mohafaza':['loc1','loc3','loc2','loc5','loc4'],
                 ' number_person ':[24,39,20,10,33],})

print(df)
        
non_numeric_cols = [col for col, col_type in df.dtypes.iteritems() if col_type == 'object']
if len(non_numeric_cols) > 0:
    #mask = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x : x.str.match('[0-3]?[0-9]-[0-3]?[0-9]-(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}$').any())
    mask = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x : x.str.match('^([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])(.|-|/)([1-9]|1[0-2])(.|-|/)20[0-9][0-9]$').any())
            
    if mask.any() == True:
        df.loc[:,mask] = df.loc[:,mask].apply(pd.to_datetime,dayfirst=False)
        converteddate = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype == 'datetime64[ns]']
    df = df.rename(columns={converteddate[0]: 'date'})
    if "date" in df.columns:
        df['year_month'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y/%m'))
        
    print(df)
```

which produces

```
     event_type       date event_mohafaza   number_person 
0  watch movie   8/11/2020           loc1               24
1  stay at home  2/13/2020           loc3               39
2      swimming  7/04/2020           loc2               20
3       camping  1/22/2020           loc5               10
4       meeting  7/28/2020           loc4               33
     event_type       date event_mohafaza   number_person  year_month
0  watch movie  2020-08-11           loc1               24    2020/08
1  stay at home 2020-02-13           loc3               39    2020/02
2      swimming 2020-07-04           loc2               20    2020/07
3       camping 2020-01-22           loc5               10    2020/01
4       meeting 2020-07-28           loc4               33    2020/07
```

You are not replacing the 'date'-column but rather adding a 'year_month' column (I left that as is).

Comment: your solution was right thanks but can you explain more the regex pattern ?

Comment: its very close to what you have, the restrictions to the date numbers is the same. What I have really added is the more general separator (.|-|/), this allows for any separation (but for space, this could also be added). Thats it really, you were close.